# Issue with date formatting in Perl

Tags: perl

I have the following code:

```
    $epoc = $rs->{'lastlogin'};
    $date = localtime($epoc);
```

`lastlogin` is a Unix timestamp.

The output is as follows: `Tue Jul 5 13:46:43 2016`

I'm looking for `Tue Jul 5 2016 13:46:43`. As you can see, the year is moved to the left one position.

I am also a newbie so I tried a few matches from here: [Date and time functions in Perl](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_date_time.htm), but I could not find a match for date formatting from a Unix timestamp.

Comment: have you tried `$date = strftime "%a %b %e %Y %H:%M:%S ", $localtime($epoc);` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The core [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) overloads the built-in `localtime` function so that it returns an object with an `strftime` method, allowing you to format the result as your wish

(`localtime` continues to perform in the same way for all other operations, so you are not losing any functionality.)

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Time::Piece;

my $rs = { lastlogin => 1467726403 };

my $epoc = $rs->{lastlogin};
my $date = localtime($epoc)->strftime('%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S');

print $date, "\n";
```

#### Output

```
Tue Jul 05 2016 14:46:43
```

---

To change the time to 12-hour, you need to use the `%I` format specifier for the hours instead of `%H`, and add `%P` at the end to provide `AM` or `PM`:

```
my $date = localtime($epoc)->strftime('%a %b %d %Y %I:%M:%S %P');
```

#### Output

```
Tue Jul 05 2016 02:46:43 PM
```

Answer (score 5):

The function `POSIX::strftime` is your friend. The first parameter is a format string and for the remaining parameters the result of `localtime()` (or `gmtime()`) can be used, i.e. `$year`, `$month`, …. The format string looks a bit similar to the format string of `printf` but allows for some special characters. They are explained [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime), for example.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $epoc = 1467743128;
print POSIX::strftime( '%a %b %e %Y %H:%M:%S', localtime($epoc) ), "\n";
```

Output:

```
Di Jul  5 2016 20:25:28
```

("Di" is short for "Dienstag" which is "Tuesday" in English.)

The `strftime` function and its parameters are also explained it the [link you provided yourself](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_date_time.htm). Just scroll down and look there.

---

You might be confused about the behaviour of `localtime`. When you write

```
my $date = localtime($epoc);
```

then `localtime` is evaluated in *scalar context*. I.e. `localtime` notices that you assign its return value to a scalar (a simple variable, not a list). In that case it returns a printable string that resembles the date and timestamp. But when `localtime` is used in *list context*, then it returns a tuple (a list) with `($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst)` instead.

In `POSIX::strftime( '%a %b %e %Y %H:%M:%S', localtime($epoc) )` `localtime` is evaluated in list context and that's exactly what `strftime` expects: a format string and a list.

```
my $date = localtime($epoc);    # scalar context
print POSIX::strftime( '%a %b %e %Y %H:%M:%S', $date ), "\n"; # doesn't work

my @date = localtime($epoc);    # list context (notice the "@")
print POSIX::strftime( '%a %b %e %Y %H:%M:%S', @date ), "\n"; # works
```